# Load XML data with repeating nodes into different rows in Teradata Table

Tags: xml, xpath, teradata, xmltable

I have an XML data with the following format:

```
<Customer>
<Name>John Hancock</Name>
<Address>100 1st Street, San Francisco, CA 94118</Address>
<Phone>(858)555-1234</Phone>
<Phone>(858)555-9876</Phone>
<Fax>(858)555-9999</Fax>
<Email>John@somecompany.com</Email>
</Customer>
```

I am transforming this data using the XMLTABLE function in Teradata and using the following query:

```
SELECT X.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM VMTEST.customer WHERE customerID = 2) AS C,
XMLTable ( '/Customer' PASSING C.customerXML
           COLUMNS "Name" VARCHAR(255) PATH 'Name',
                   "Address" VARCHAR(255) PATH 'Address',
                   "Phone" VARCHAR(255) PATH 'Phone' ) AS X
```

This gives me the result as shown in image and appends the Phone fields.

[Resultset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwLhE.png)

I want to take the 2nd Phone to a new row. Is it possible to do such operation using the Xpath queries? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution and sharing for others facing similar issue

```
SELECT X.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM VMTEST.customer WHERE customerID = 2) AS C,
       xmltable('Customer/Phone' passing c.customerXML
       Columns "NAME" varchar(255) path '../Name',
       Address varchar (255) path '../Address',
       Phone varchar (255) path '.'
     )
     as X
```